# How to install the tailwind elements in nextjs?

Tags: next.js

I am installing the tailwind elements for the slider in nextjs,
but it is not working in the nextjs there is any solution to install it in an easy way.

[I follow this method][1]
[1]: https://tailwind-elements.com/quick-start/
When I adding this import 'tw-elements';
Then it show me an error

Comment: Just saying "it is not working" makes it difficult to understand the problem. Can you provide more details, please? What steps have you taken so far? Are there any error messages? If so, what are they? Etc.

Answer (score 14):

A user solved this in the issues in Github. It worked for me so hopefully it will work for you, here is the [link to the issue](https://github.com/mdbootstrap/Tailwind-Elements/issues/1058#issuecomment-1176988692).

in your `_app.js` file update to :

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {


useEffect(() => {
const use = async () => {
  (await import('tw-elements')).default;
    };
    use();
  }, []);

  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: This works even though the `import dynamic from "next/dynamic";` way doesn't. Weird.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and the fix is quite simple. In your project go and edit node_modules/tw-elements/dist/js/index.min.js

At the very beginning change

```
function(n){
```

for this

```
function(n){if (typeof window == "undefined")return;
```

Voila!!

NOTE: If you are using VErcel or any other Nextjs hosting for your project you will notice that it automatically download all modules, so the changes you made in your local project are not reflected in the deployment.

Fortunately you can run a pre-build command in Vercel:

1. Go to Project settings_>General
2. Override the Build command
3. Put this in the field:

   sed -i 's/function(n){var r={};function o(t)/function(n){if(typeof window == "undefined")return;var r={};function o(t)/g' node_modules/tw-elements/dist/js/index.min.js; next build

Well... it's crappy and ugly but it works

Comment: it is really ugly way to get it to work, why hasn't anybody informed the tw-element authors?
or other way would be is to locally store the JS file.

Comment: I can't seem to make it work tho. I've put the if in the file but the components don't work

Comment: watch the exclaimation symbol before !function.

Comment: on MacOS its - 

sed -i '' 's/!function(n){var r={};function o(t)/!function(n){if(typeof window == "undefined")return;var r={};function o(t)/g' node_modules/tw-elements/dist/js/index.min.js; node_modules/tw-elements/dist/js/index.min.js; next build