# How to install the tailwind elements in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-elements

I saw another question about installing tailwind elements in nextjs project.
[How to install the tailwind elements in nextjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71875270/how-to-install-the-tailwind-elements-in-nextjs)
I followed it on my react project.It doesn't work. How can use tailwind elements in react project?

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
// import "tw-elements";

const Stepper = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const use = async () => {
      await import("tw-elements");
    };
    use();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <ul
        className="stepper"
        data-mdb-stepper="stepper"
        data-mdb-stepper-type="vertical"
      >
        <li className="stepper-step stepper-active">
          <div className="stepper-head">
            <span className="stepper-head-icon"> 1 </span>
            <span className="stepper-head-text"> step1 </span>
          </div>
          <div className="stepper-content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
            eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
          </div>
        </li>
        <li className="stepper-step">
          <div className="stepper-head">
            <span className="stepper-head-icon"> 2 </span>
            <span className="stepper-head-text"> step2 </span>
          </div>
          <div className="stepper-content">
            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
            nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          </div>
        </li>
        <li className="stepper-step">
          <div className="stepper-head">
            <span className="stepper-head-icon"> 3 </span>
            <span className="stepper-head-text"> step3 </span>
          </div>
          <div className="stepper-content">
            Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};
```

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./node_modules/tw-elements/dist/js/**/*.js",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require("tw-elements/dist/plugin")],
};
```

The code above is what i write to stepper. It work sometime, but sometime it doesn't . stepper-content is never hided or never showed.  Am i did something wrong? Thank you
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [link](https://github.com/mdbootstrap/Tailwind-Elements/issues/1058), you should import tw-elements in a useEffect in the _app file, not in the same component that you use them in.

/_app.jsx/tsx

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const use = async () => {
      (await import('tw-elements')).default;
    };
    use();
  }, []);

  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default MyApp;
```

There is also another solution to use the _document.js file and Script element to use the script for tw_elements

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
import Script from 'next/script'

// import 'tw-elements';

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html>
      <Head />
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
        <Script src="./TW-ELEMENTS-PATH/dist/js/index.min.js"/>
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
}
```

but I don't recommend it as _document.js will be replaced soon in the upcoming updates for NextJS

Comment: Import package in reactJS project . is it the same?

Comment: I didn't try it in react, but I assume you will want to import it in your index.jsx file inc ase of a react project so that it would be accessible by the whole app